# Keyboard not working in Nautilus

Tags: gnome, keyboard, nautilus

I used to have Debian Jessie with GNOME (I do not know the version though).
I had to reinstall Debian and I decided to stick to the same Debian Version Jessie 8.11. I installed the GNOME version which was suggested as default during the installation (GNOME 3.14.1).

I have been experiencing an issue with NAUTILUS since this reinstallation of GNOME: the keyboard does not work when I use the "search" feature, or when I create a new folder or when I try to rename a folder or a file by left click.

I don't think it is a matter of permissions, though, as I manage to rename or create folders by command line.

Thanks and cheers

Comment: Does this happen immediately after  logging in to gnome?

Comment: No. This issue is always there